# Can we change IONiC 3 badge icon style

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

I developed a hybrid app with IONIC 3 and I want to change the badge push notification ion of the app. Is it possible to change badge icon styling as showing in the sample Facebook icon?

Facebook sample badge icon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are able to change the color of the badge in Android. iOS won't let you modify the badge at all. This is to be cohesive with their entire platform look.

*This will let you work on badges in the application:*
https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#badges

*This will let you work on the badges on the icon:*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888608/5144902

Comment: Actually i am looking badge icon when app is not running as showing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921127/is-it-possible-to-change-color-of-hybrid-app-badge-icon?noredirect=1#comment76818134_44921127

Comment: Please let me know if is it possible

Comment: Unless the phone is jail-broken, you cannot change the stylizing of the badge on iOS.

Comment: Thanks, is any other work around to achieve this functionality?

Comment: iOS will probably never open up this functionality. Focusing this on Android is probably your best bet.