# Is it possible to change color of hybrid app badge icon?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

Is it possible to change hybrid app badge icon styling like background color?
By default its background color is red and it shows as round shape. Can we change these styling?

Is it possible with native app?

[image]

Comment: On iOS, the badge style is set by the operating system and cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks for response, and what about Android devices?

Comment: No idea about Android, sorry.

Comment: Is there any chance to add any symbol before the push notification count on IOS or Android devices?

Comment: Not on iOS; the badge is simply a number